# 'Declaration is Incompatible with' error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, declaration, incomplete-type

Error: Declaration is incompatible with "void DateType::setBirthYear(& birthYear)"

The same error with month and day.

There's no compile error, no runtime error, but the methods are never called properly and produce no toString output. Visual Studio keeps saying the cpp definition is incompatible with the h declaration, despite them being exactly the same. I have another class in the same project which follows the same format albeit with different methods for setting different variables, and that one has no errors whatsoever, and its toString works fine.

Header File:

```
#ifndef DATETYPE_H
#define DATETYPE_H
using namespace std;
#include <string>


class DateType
{
public:
    DateType(void);
    ~DateType(void);
    void setBirthMonth(string& birthMonth);
    void setBirthDay(string& birthDay);
    void setBirthYear(string& birthyear);
    string toString();
private:
    string month;
    string day;
    string year;
};

#endif
```

cpp file:

```
#include "DateType.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

DateType::DateType(void)
{
}
DateType::~DateType(void)
{
}

void DateType::setBirthMonth(string& birthMonth){
    month=birthMonth;
    cout<<month;
}
void DateType::setBirthDay(string& birthDay){
    day=birthDay;
    cout<<day;
}
void DateType::setBirthYear(string& birthYear){
    year=birthYear;
    cout<<year;
    toString();
}
string DateType::toString(){
    cout<<month+" "+day+ " "+year;
    return (month+" "+day+ " "+year);
}
```

Comment: If there is no compile error then what is `"Error: Declaration is incompatible with "void DateType::setBirthYear(& birthYear)"` ??

Comment: Don't put `using namespace std;` in header files.

Comment: `but the methods are never called properly and produce no toString output`  Well, nothing is called if you have no `main` function, and I don't see that you posted one.